# Button that expands ComboBox causing infinite loop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have button on top of my comboBox, I received the element from other developer like that and I cannot change it drastically. What I need to happen is when I hover over the button the comboBox will open, when I leave it will close. When I click the button it will trigger a function. The problem is when I hover over the button the comboBox get focus and I get stuck in infinite loop of open close (maybe there is something else wrong). But it does not work.

```
<Grid Margin="10,0,10,0" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="85*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Height="30" Name="Combo2"
              Style="{StaticResource CategoryComboBox}"
              SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged2"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Grid.Column="0">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBox Item 1 (Example)" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBox Item 2 (Example)" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBox Item 3 (Example)" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBox Item 4 (Example)" />
    </ComboBox>
    <Button MouseEnter="MouseEnter2" MouseLeave="MouseLeave2" Name="Menu_Btn2"
            Click="GotoMenu" Style="{StaticResource CategoryButton}" Grid.Column="0"
            Content="Category Name 2" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontSize="16"
            FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#Univers LT Std 57 Cn" />
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
private void MouseEnter2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Combo2.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}

private void MouseLeave2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Combo2.IsDropDownOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: This is broken by design. I recommend using the controls the way they were intended to. Pursuing this will give you headaches when debugging this, chasing events and states and for the user this will always be broken because it doesn't follow the normal/expected behaviour of the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first idea would be to unsubscribe from the MouseEnter2-Event at the moment you enter the button. In the MouseLeave2-Event you have to subscribe again for the MouseEnter2. Maybe this works for you

To unsubscribe from the MouseEnter2-Event you have to:

```
button.MouseEnter -= MouseEnter2;
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Actually, maybe it's better to subscribe to the MouseLeave event in the dropdown open event.